# Are there drawbacks to sqlite as archivation format?

Tags: backup, tar, archiving, sqlite, file-archiver

I have a few huge folders of small files I want to archive for long term storage (about 200GB).

Instead of just using something like gzip/tar/dar/7zip I am considering to use sqlite

> sqlite3 Backup.db ".ar -cv Data"

Disregarding the compression, am I going towards some pitfalls? Are there any advantages old simple tar would have?

Answer (score 4):

The primary disadvantage: you need an `sqlite3` executable *with archive support* when you need to recover your data. Depending on the circumstances, you may not have one handy, but you're far more likely to find a working `gzip`, `tar` *et al*.

Here's why I'm being particularly pedantic about this:

- macOS system `sqlite3` versions are generally within spitting distance of up-to-date, but Apple only updates its software sporadically, and many Mac users may run backdated OSes for various reasons. Consequently, macOS system `sqlite3` before Mojave does *not* support archiving, so for portability, you'll definitely want to ensure that the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) sqlite3 package is installed *and updated*.
- Homebrew on Linux defaults to installing a bottled (i.e. precompiled binary) sqlite v3.26 that somehow manages to *not* support archiving. I had to `brew install --build-from-source sqlite3` to fix that.

Those are just two examples that I have personal experience with. The platforms on which you plan to sqlar may have similar gotchas. Contrast all that with "it just works everywhere" `gzip`/`tar`/etc.

So, if you want to use the sqlar format in earnest, carefully consider all the circumstances and *environments* in which you'll be doing so. A rescue disk, for instance, may not have an archiving `sqlite3`, and you really don't want to build sqlite from scratch during disaster recovery.

---

Aside from the availability of an archive-capable `sqlite3`, you also need to consider the issue of *file sizes*.

Since an sqlar is basically an SQLite DB, it inherits [all the limits](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) of this file format. In particular, each file's data is stored as a BLOB, which has a default maximum size of **1 billion bytes**. Also, SQLite query processing leads to each row being handled as a single BLOB, further lowering the file size limit.

Compare that with [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) (2<sup>32</sup> for "classic ZIP", 2<sup>64</sup> for ZIP64) or [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Formats.html) (unlimited), and you may have yet another reason to take the traditional route instead.